# Permission denied to a repository when starting Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, permissions, dependencies

I started to get this error message, when I run my 20.04 Ubuntu.

[image: Vivaldi repository permission denied error]

When I run `sudo apt-get update` + `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I get `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded` - but still showing the same error message when I restart.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You’re going to want to throw a `sudo` in front of that command: `sudo apt update` 

Comment: @Matigo  yes, when I do that, then `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded` but I still get the error when I restart.

Comment: @karel That doesn't address the *original* error in the image

Comment: The error in the linked duplicate question is `W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)` which is the same as the error in this question.

Answer (score 1):

Following the advice from the Vivaldi forum, I just deleted the file & then `sudo apt update`; the error message after restart has not re-appeared, so for now I leave it as solved.